# Forking a rpm into two

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I need to fork a rpm into two rpm because of being two separate products.

Formerly both product were using "reporter.rpm". Now, they will use
"reporter-product1.rpm" and "reporter-product2.rpm", respectively.
These rpm's will be required by a base rpm for each product,
"base-product1.rpm" and "base-product2.rpm", repectively.

```
reporter |-> reporter-product1
         |-> reporter-product2
```

If I only add "Provides: reporter" two each rpm, a "yum update" will
give a **"file something from install of reporter-product1.rpm conflicts
with file from package reporter.rpm"**

If I only add "Obsoletes: reporter" two each rpm, a "yum update" will
give a **"Error: Missing depedency: reporter >= 1.3.2 is needed by
package base-product1.rpm"** and **"Error: Missing depedency: reporter >=
1.3.2 is needed by package base-product2.rpm"**

If I both add "Obsoletes: reporter" and "Provides: reporter" two each
rpm, a "yum update" will **try to install both packages**
(reporter-product1.rpm and reporter-product2.rpm) because they both
obsoletes reporter.rpm

What do you suggest in this case?

Best Regards,

Comment: Are you saying that *either* will satisfy all the requirements of existing packages? And that they shouldn't be installed at the same time?

Comment: Yes. According to the product only one of them should be installed.

Comment: I'm not sure you can have two packages obsolete one package AND have both packages conflict with each other.  Yum/rpm will assume that both packages need to be installed in order to upgrade from the old package, but both packages cannot be simultaneously installed.  I suggest making only one rpm obsolete `reporter` and having both rpms `Conflict:` each other.